# Deploying OpenCL application?

Tags: c++, opencl

I am currently learning OpencL and am finding it somewhat difficult to understand how it actually works.
I am using MinGW compiler with ATI APP SDK.
When I run the target I get error message

[image]

I have not placed any OpenCL.dll in the same folder as my application.
Now searching a bit on Windows I can find this dll in

```
C:/Windows/SysWOW64
C:/Windows/System32/DriverStore/...
C:/Windows/System32
C:/Program Files(x86)/AMD APP SDK /...
```

So my question is how should I deploy my application?
Should I distribute OpenCL.dll with my application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why your application can't find clReleaseDevice is because you wrote your application to the OpenCL 1.2 headers but you only have a OpenCL 1.1 runtime on your machine. You can't call OpenCL 1.2 API on an OpenCL 1.1 runtime. I recommend using the OpenCL 1.1 headers unless you only run on OpenCL 1.2 devices. It will keep your code safe for running on OpenCL 1.1 platforms and devices.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. I agree with what you say. So what do you recommend? Should I stick with OpenCL 1.2 or 1.1? It really boils down to how better is 1.2 compared to 1.1 vs how much market is captured by 1.1

Comment: OpenCL 1.1 has more market share as it is supported by both Nvidia and AMD.  If you can live without OpenCL 1.2 features then go with OpenCL 1.1.  If OpenCL 1.2 features provide a significant speed boost vs. OpenCL 1.1 then write two code paths, one for OpenCL 1.1 and another for OpenCL 1.2.  Then ship the OpenCL 1.2 DLL with your application and make sure you only use OpenCL 1.2 code on OpenCL 1.2 platforms, otherwise your application will segfault.

Comment: I agree with what "chippies" added except the part about redistributing the OpenCL.DLL -- if your platform says it is 1.2 then you can make 1.2 calls without redistributing any DLL. The key point is that you can't make 1.2 calls until you've determined that you have a 1.2 platform & device.

Comment: @Dithermaster currently I have added the OpenCL code in a sepparate class which has no static members/functions. No object of this class is created and header of this class is not included in any other class. So that means I am not using any OpenCL code at all! Then when I launch my application why do I get this error? The debugger is also not able to enter the code. So this means there is some startup linking issue. If this is true then my application wont start on a PC which does not have OpenCL at all. What do you suggest I should do then? Do you understand my concern?

Comment: Does this mean I have to provide 2 versions of my application - one without OpenCL and one with OpenCL? Is this not more of a hack rather than a solution to the problem? And this is a generic issue, so others must have found a solution to this problem? Please let me know if you did not understand my doubts.

Comment: @chippies I decided to stick with OpenCL 1.1 as it has all I require. Thanks for your information. But now I am finding it hard to understand whether the same exe built using OpenCL will run on a hardware which does not have OpenCL or maybe has only 1.0 drivers. Please provide your valuable inputs.

Comment: @Cool_Coder I'll try to sum up. What Dithermaster says is the right way to handle dependencies on 3rd party DLLs that have their own installers (like AMD's or Nvidia's drivers).  You will have to write code that loads the DLL functions you plan on using.  This code will have to load both the OpenCL 1.1 and 1.2 functions to avoid any linking to the OpenCL.dll (which causes the original error).  The procedure would go something along the lines of search for OpenCL.dll, if found then try to load all the functions needed using  LoadLibrary / GetProcAddress.

Comment: @Cool_Coder If CL1.2 functions loaded then check that platform supports CL1.2. If it does then use CL1.2 code path, else check for CL1.1 support and, if available, use that code path. If CL1.1 is not available then go to the CPU only code path. If no CL functions were loaded / OpenCL.dll not found then go straight to CPU code path. Checking that the CL platform supports CL1.2 even though OpenCL.dll provides the CL1.2 functions is necessary if there are multiple platforms and one of them doesn't support CL1.2.  The DLL will provide the functions, but calling them on a CL1.1 platform segfaults.

Comment: Correct. On Windows there are two ways to handle OpenCL.dll being optional: do it dynamically manually (using LoadLibrary / GetProcAddress) or let the OS do it dynamically for you (using the /DELAYLOAD linker option).

Comment: @Dithermaster Has anyone written a library that loads the OpenCL 1.2 functions and returns errors or throws an exception if OpenCL is not available?

Comment: @chippies and Dithermaster thanks for summarising and clearing my confusion. I now have full understanding of how to tackle my problem. Now I just need to search what is dynamic loading and delayload. Thanks to both for your help!

Answer (score 5):

Dissenting opinion: You should *never* redistribute OpenCL.dll with your application! It belongs in the system folder and should only be installed by OpenCL drivers from the platform providers (Apple, NVIDIA, AMD, Intel, etc.). If your system doesn't have it installed, shipping your own with your application isn't going to make it run any better since you don't have an OpenCL platform for it to find.

Comment: How then should someone go about writing an app that targets both OpenCL 1.1 and 1.2 devices.  It seems to me that one would have to compile two versions of your application and have the app installer only install the appropriate one.  However, your code targeting OpenCL 1.2 would still need a fallback path for OpenCL 1.1 devices and platforms when there is a mix of OpenCL 1.1 and 1.2 on the same machine.

Comment: Call the 1.1 APIs directly and use dynamic methods for the 1.2 APIs, then you won't get the "entry point not found" error. On Windows this would be LoadLibrary / GetProcAddress.

Comment: @Dithermaster thank you for educating me.  One question though, looking at OpenCL.dll installed on my PC, I see that it identifies itself as the Khronos OpenCL ICD.  How will this ICD loader respond if there are no OpenCL implementations that have been registered?  I was under the impression that the ICD loader was supposed to shield me from this problem.

Comment: @Dithermaster after doing some more reading I get the impression that the reason for not distributin OpenCL.dll is that it stops the application from taking advantage of some later update to the ICD, e.g. for bug fixes.  I also found this thread that covers this topic: [http://www.khronos.org/message_boards/showthread.php/6299-OpenCL-ICD-infrastructure-questions](http://www.khronos.org/message_boards/showthread.php/6299-OpenCL-ICD-infrastructure-questions), which echoes your advice.

Comment: @chippies: If you have the ICD but no drivers, then clGetPlatformIDs returns 0.

Comment: ICD means OpenCL.dll right? Is there any other dll which needs to be in the path?

Comment: @Cool_Coder ICD==Installable Client Driver. There was a time in the early days of OpenCL when each vendor had their own OpenCL.dll, making it difficult to have multiple vendors on one PC, but we are long past that era.  The OpenCL.dll located in system32 should be the ICD loader.  Each vendor registers their own ICD and the ICD loader just finds and reports all of these. Have a look at the extension spec for more info: [https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/extensions/khr/cl_khr_icd.txt](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/extensions/khr/cl_khr_icd.txt)

Comment: @Cool_Coder No other DLLs are needed directly by your application. Vendor specific DLLs don't need to be on the PATH variable because, in Windows, they must be recorded in a specific part of the registry so that the ICD loader finds them.

Comment: @chippies thanks for understanding my problem and spending some valuable time out of your schedule to help me out. That really helped understand a lot of OpenCL which unfortunately I could not find on the internet.

Comment: @Cool_Coder I learned something too from Dithermaster by trying to answer your question.  I work mostly in Java with javacl that hides all this from me so I have never had to learn this before.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you should distribute **all** non standard dll's with your application. You can either put it in the same folder as the application, this makes it easy to deinstall the application, just delete the folder. Or if you use an installer put it in the system folder (using the installer) of the target system. Usually a good installer should be able to determine the system target folder.

Windows will search the dll first in the executable path and then in the system path. As you can read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18.aspx). So it usually makes no difference for your application where you put it in. Except the loading of your app will extend a little bit.

Comment: Thanks it worked! Just to make it clear, I need to distribute the dll from the SDK bin folder and it is platform independent i.e. it will run on NVIDIA, Intel or any other processing unit?

Comment: The DLL from the AMD APP SDK should work on Nvidia GPUs until you call a function that only exists in OpenCL 1.2, then your application will segfault.  Just make sure you have separate code paths for OpenCL 1.1 and 1.2 to avoid this.

Comment: @chippies as answered by Dithermaster this is not the correct solution. Redistributing the dll is not correct. Can you provide references for the correct method?

Answer (score 2):

yes, according to the "hello world" example in the [SDK documentation](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/heterogeneous-computing/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/introductory-tutorial-to-opencl/) you should have OpenCL.dll somewhere on your path.  It will need this to connect your software call to the kernel running on the device.

Note that in general Windows looks for .dll files according to the [PATH environment variable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18.aspx) (after looking in the current directory / system directories)