# Creating OpenCL 1.1 compliant application using AMD APP SDK 2.9?

Tags: c++, opencl

AMD has kept only 2.9, 2.8 and 2.7 versions of its SDK [online](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/heterogeneous-computing/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/downloads/download-archive/) all of which are for OpenCL 1.2.
I want to have my application to be compatible with OpenCL 1.1 hardware.
Since I am stuck with up with a 1.2 SDK and don't have much hardware support for testing I wanted to know what is the right way to do this?

1. I downloaded the 1.1 headers from Khronos website and used them with my MinGW compiler.
   The application works on my ATI GPU with only OpenCL 1.1 drivers but I don't know for sure whether I am right or not. I have this doubt because I am still linking the OpenCL.lib from the SDK which is OpenCL 1.2.
2. Also should I distribute the OpenCL.dll from SDK with my application?
3. What is the best way to avoid an [error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22098210/deploying-opencl-application) in non compatible hardware by disabling the OpenCL code so that at least everything else runs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at cl.h header:

Every API function has macro, that defines to which version does it belong:

```
extern CL_API_ENTRY CL_EXT_PREFIX__VERSION_1_1_DEPRECATED cl_mem CL_API_CALL
clCreateImage2D(cl_context              /* context */,
                cl_mem_flags            /* flags */,
                const cl_image_format * /* image_format */,
                size_t                  /* image_width */,
                size_t                  /* image_height */,
                size_t                  /* image_row_pitch */, 
                void *                  /* host_ptr */,
                cl_int *                /* errcode_ret */) CL_EXT_SUFFIX__VERSION_1_1_DEPRECATED;
```

So, to make your application OpenCL 1.1 compliant, use functions from version 1.1 and older. Take into account, that may functions (like clCreateImage2D) are deprecated in new API versions. In that case you need to define CL_USE_DEPRECATED_OPENCL_1_1_APIS macro - but I don't know if it's good practice.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Now suppose my application is OpenCL 1.1 compliant and works fine. But if it is run on hardware below that version it will show an error message and my application wont start at all. How do I disable OpenCL for hardware that does not support it?

Comment: Same principle is applied - you should use API from version 1.0. All major vendors support OpenCL 1.1, so situation you've described is hard to be

Comment: @Cool_Coder The simplest thing is to ask first device for which OpenCL version it support using clGetPlatformInfo and CL_PLATFORM_VERSION combination. If it is below your requirement you print the warning message and divert the path to C implementation.

Comment: @Sagar I already have a question on this topic but I am finding contradicting answers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22098210/deploying-opencl-application. Can you pitch in and provide the correct solution based on your valuable experience on OpenCL?

Comment: @Roman I refering to a situation where OpenCL is not supported at all. This can be possible on a PC which has moderately old CPU and no GPU. Its ok if I cannot use OpenCL but atleast my application should work...

Comment: Then you need to check If OpenCL library is present (via Cmake or sh if distributing source, or by dynamical linking against OpenCL lib) and switch to GPU \ CPU implementation.

Comment: understood how to tackle this situation now. Thanks for your help!