# Distribution of an application that uses OpenCL

Tags: windows, opencl, intel, amd-processor

I would like to distribute a Windows/Linux application that uses OpenCL, but I can't find the best way to do it.

For the moment my problem are only on Windows:

1. I'm using Intel CPU, how can I manage Intel AND AMD (CPU of final users) ?
2. For distribution of application that uses Visual Studio DLL, we have Visual Studio Redistributable to manage this easily and to avoid a big installation of Visual Studio. Is there a package like this for OpenCL ?
3. Finally, I don't know if I must provide OpenCL.dll or not (example of different point of view [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22098210/deploying-opencl-application))

I read several topics on the web about this problem without clear solution.

Comment: OpenCL is not concerned with the CPU's ISA, but the GPU's. Usually you only need one x64 build for all Intel (IA-64) and AMD (AMD64) users. Only distribute two (or more) binaries if you have actually profiled your code on different processors with different compilers and optimization optiions and found performance differences that justify it.

Comment: Ok, it can explain why I didn't find information about this topic, it was just a misunderstanding. So I think there is no problem to provide OpenCL.dll with my application ?

Comment: @Dai: IA-64 is Itanium.  x86-64 is sometimes called IA-32e in Intel's manuals.  Libraries *do* need to run on the CPU to send instructions to the GPU, so they do need to match the ISA of the CPU.  For example, an AArch64 OpenCL library won't work on x86-64.  The key point is that **x86-64 is still x86-64 whether you have an Intel or AMD CPU**.  They both implement the same architecture, sometimes with different extensions or performance.

Comment: No, opencl.dll is not needed in package. Program uses/finds it through drivers automatically. Why visual studio dll? Query opencl for cpu devices only, to find user's cpu.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, I don't mean to imply that an `opencl.dll` built for ARM will somehow work on an x86 machine

Comment: @Dai: I forgot to say in the last comment that x86-32 vs. x86-64 still matters, because those are also different ISAs.  So ISA matters, but ISA extensions like FMA or AVX512 probably don't.

Answer (score 3):

1) You write to the OpenCL API and it works with whatever hardware your user has. User the header for the lower version you want to support (e.g., use cl.h from 1.1 if you want to target 1.1 and higher).

2) The OpenCL runtime is installed on the user's machine when they install a graphics driver. You don't need to (and should not) redistribute anything.

3) Please don't redistribute OpenCL.dll

The one problem you may need to deal with is if your user does not have any OpenCL installed on their machine. In this case, the call to clGetPlatformIDs will fail. There are various ways to deal with this, all platform specific. Dynamically linking to OpenCL.dll is one way, or running a helper process to test for OpenCL is another. An elegant solution on Windows is to delay load OpenCL.dll and hook that API to return 0 if the late binding fails.

Comment: Ok. I don't understand your last comment, if OpenCL runtime is installed when user install graphics driver, it means everybody will have OpenCL installed on their modern machine, so theoretically they will not have problem, no?

Comment: On Windows, it's still possible to not have a GPU driver, and the "Basic Graphics" driver that comes with Windows doesn't have OpenCL.

Answer (score -1):

> 1- I'm using Intel CPU, how can I manage Intel AND AMD (CPU of final users)

Are you talking about running OpenCL kernels on CPU, or just host-side code while kernels run on GPU ? because if the former (on CPU), your users will need to install their respective OpenCL CPU implementation, IIRC the Intel CPU implementation does not run on AMDs (or at least that used to be the case, perhaps it's now different..)

> 3- Finally, I don't know if I must provide OpenCL.dll

You don't have to, but you should, IMO. The way OpenCL works (usually), OpenCL.dll is just an ICD loader - a small library (a few dozen KB) that loads the actual OpenCL implementation(s) by looking into a few predefined places. It should be safe to include on Windows, and it simplifies your program logic - you can always build with OpenCL enabled, and if there's no OpenCL implementation installed, the loader will return CL_PLATFORM_NOT_FOUND_KHR - you just handle that error by asking user to install an OpenCL implementation, or fallback to non-OpenCL code path if you have it, whatever suits you more.

There's no need to complicate your life with delayed DLL loads or helper processes. In fact that's the entire point of the ICD concept - you don't need to look for the platforms and DLLs yourself, you let the ICD loader do it. It's pretty absurd to write helper code to load a helper library (ICD) which then loads the actual implementation DLLs...

Comment: If you ship an OpenCL.dll, won't that interfere with users installing an OpenCL setup that uses the latest drivers for their CPU, or an optimized build for their CPU?

Comment: For the moment kernels are launched only on CPU (not on GPU). Ok, so If I understand, for GPU, OpenCL implementation is installed with driver, but it's not the same with CPU drivers. In my case, I will have a problem if user has not used OpenCL before. You said "you just handle that error by asking user to install an OpenCL implementation", it means user must install the full Intel SDK for example (in case of Intel CPU) ?

Comment: @GoblE Yes, for CPU you will need a CPU implementation. If you consider intel, AFAICT you don't need the entire SDK just the CPU runtime - so basically "OpenCL Runtime for Intel Core and Intel Xeon Processors" [from this link](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-drivers). Also from what i read in their license, you may distribute it as long as your users agree with a license [at least as restrictive as the one provided by Intel](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/56/f8/INTEL%20SOFTWARE%20LICENSE%20AGREEMENT.pdf). This might be best if it works with AMDs..

Comment: @PeterCordes i believe it should not, as the OpenCL.dll provided by drivers is also just an ICD - and any ICD (if it's not too old) should be able to load any driver. The DLLs with actual implementations are written in registry, in "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Khronos\OpenCL\Vendors" - that's where the ICD (OpenCL.dll) looks for them.